# RDU - Axios, Express and Multer

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, multer, react-dropzone

Ok so last night I posted the request at the bottom of this window.

I got up this morning and had another crack, and i'm almost there now, i'm glad to say.

My only issue, now is that, on submission i'm getting a record in mongodb for each item of data:

[image]

This is my submit function:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    // console.log({ movie });
    // console.log(files.map(f => f.meta));
    setShowLoading(true);
    e.preventDefault();
    const apiUrl = "http://localhost:5000/api/movies/";
    const headers = "multipart/form-data";
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.set("title", movie.title);
    let items = files.map(fileItem => fileItem.file);
    setPosterCollection([...posterCollection, ...items]);
    for (let img in posterCollection[0]) {
      formData.append("posters", posterCollection[0][img]);
    }
    console.log(Array.from(formData));

    axios.post(apiUrl, formData, headers)
    .then((result) => {
      setShowLoading(false);
      console.log(result);
      props.history.push('/show/' + result.data.movie._id)
    }).catch((error) => setShowLoading(false));

    // allFiles.forEach(f => f.remove());
    onSubmit();
  };
```

My route which links to my mongo model schema:

```
router.post('/', upload.array('file'), (req, res) => {

  var filenames = req.files.map(function(file) {
    return file.path; // or file.originalname
  });

  var a = (filenames.findIndex(function(item){
    return item.indexOf("poster")!==-1;
  }));

  var b = (filenames.findIndex(function(item){
      return item.indexOf("slide")!==-1;
  }));

  console.log(filenames);
  console.log(movieData);

  var date = new Date(req.body.date);
  // var isoString = date.toISOString();

  var movieData = {
    id: req.body.id,
    title: req.body.title,
    synopsis: req.body.synopsis,
    trailer: req.body.trailer,
    OpeningDate: date,
    poster:  filenames[a],
    slide: filenames[b]
  };

  let movie = new Movie(movieData);
  console.log(movie);
  movie.save()
    .then(() => res.json({ movie, msg: 'New movie added successfully' }))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Unable to add this movie'))
});
```

**LAST NIGHT:**

I am adding react-dropzone-uploader to a project of mine, for where express/axios and multer are already setup, is it at all possible to adapt react-dropzone-uploader to work alongside?

Get the likes of getUploadParams working with axios.post, and what field name should I call for multer, express?

Has anyone successfully done this? I've seen other people post about it.

My form code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-https-kgujm

It won't work fully, because it has local URL's. But hopefully someone can peruse, might be able to give me advice.

Axios sections are commented out, whilst testing. Might be up for making it worth somebody's while, with a financial donation.

Comment: It's still not quite clear what's not working and what's the desired behaviour

Comment: the desired behaviour, is all the form data text and images to be stored in mongodb.

now the form is writing to mongodb, so i'm getting data stored. but i'm not getting the formdata as 1 record, like:


ID: 00001
Title: Title Test
Content: This is the content

What i'm getting is an individual record for each input of the form, so i'm getting something like this:

ID:0001
Title: Title Test

ID:0002
Content: This is the content

Which is wrong and the part that's not working, for some reason the data is getting split up